# Kinect - Difference between Depth and Joint Position.Z

Tags: c#, kinect

It seems to me that both **depth** and **position.z** measure the distance between the body parts and the camera.

From what I see in examples and questions, (e.g.) the body parts of the tracked human being can be coloured differently based on how far they are from the camera.

As for the skeleton, the position z is limited to the joints that are available through the SDK.

So in conclusion, both provides the same function but depth is more precise. Am I having the wrong concept on depth or missing out any important points?

**I apologize if this question can be easily found on stackoverflow or on other websites. I couldn't find any pages that could answer my query so I've decided to post here instead.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth is trivially calculated per-pixel.  Joint.Z is optionally calculated per-joint.  Joint calculating has a substantial performance cost because the SDK has to analyze the image to figure out which of those millions of pixels is, for example, your left knee.  Joint has the benefit of also getting inferred by the SDK based on its understanding of human anatomy so if your left knee happens to be occluded by a wandering puppy, the Joint position will still be pretty accurate because assumptions are made based on other visible joints.

If you are already doing skeleton tracking for x,y of joints then you might as well take advantage of the z that comes with it but otherwise depth will be more efficient.

Comment: ah, okay thank you for your help, I thought I wouldn't be able to get an answer after so long. Thanks :)